# Java - Object Type Casting and Inheritance

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance, casting

I have superclass A, which is extended by subclasses B1 and B2. Then, I have five subclasses (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5) that extend either B1 or B2.

I am trying to make an array containing one of each of these five subclasses.

These objects are all instantiated as instances of type A.

```
ClassA[] objects = new ClassA[5];
```

I attempt to reassign each of the objects to one of the subclasses:

```
objects[0] = new ClassC1;
objects[1] = new ClassC2;  // etc...
```

At this point, any methods that existed in Class A work fine, but methods defined in B1/B2 or the other subclasses are not found:

```
objects[0].MethodFromC1();   // returns a "symbol not found" error
```

The instanceof keyword indicates that objects[0] is an instance of classes A, B1/B2, and C1.

What can I do to maintain my array of class objects (to loop through and perform operations), while getting my code to recognize the methods of the subclasses?

Comment: Would it be feasible to create a common (or abstract) method in `ClassA` that can be implemented / overwritten by the subclasses? That way, you need not worry about which object is of which concrete type, you simply invoke your generic `doSomething` method, and the individual objects will behave appropriately for their type.

Comment: As @Teeg says, you want an abstract base class, and override the desired methods in the derived classes.

Comment: You want to be able to create heterogenous containers, and avoid the strong typing of Java, but you just need to think polymorphism.  This and other reasons why I find myself writing more Ruby (scala, clojure, any lisp variant would suffice).

Comment: What you say would work, but I'm trying to not have any methods in the subclass that aren't used. I have a few abstract methods in my Class A, but the methods in Class B1/B2 are more specific and wouldn't apply to all the subclasses.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing a lot of `instanceof` and conditional logic based on class, you are completely missing out on the benefits of an object-oriented language. Just stick to C.

You should have some method `do()`, for example, that is abstract in `ClassA` but implemented in `ClassB` and `ClassC`. Then you iterate over the array and call `do()` on every object in there. The polymorphic call will result in the right `do()`'s being called.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the instanceof keyword in the if statement and cast the object to the desired type. For example,

```
for (ClassA obj : objects) {
    // do something common...

    if (obj instanceof ClassC1) {
        ClassC1 c1Obj = (ClassC1) obj;
        c1Obj.MethodFromC1();
    }
}
```

Comment: When trying to implement as a foreach loop I receive an error stating that the variable (c10bj equivalent) may not be initialized. I know that for more primitive types the solution is to just set the variable explicitly (int x = 0, etc), but I'm unsure how to proceed with objects.

Comment: Sorry. There was a mistake in the code, which is fixed now. You should type cast the `obj` variable to `ClassC1`.

Answer (score 1):

Elements in the `objects` array don't know anything about `ClassC1` since they're only guaranteed to be members of `ClassA`.

For instance, if you have a class hierarchy of `Animal` and subclass `Cat` and its subclass `Lion`, you're trying to call the `Animal.maimSafarigoer()` method. `Animal`s in general don't know anything about safarigoers, only `Lion`s know how to do that.

Use the `instanceof` operator to check if you're operating on a particular subtype.

(Sorry for the gruesome analogy. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to implement variants in Java. This subject has long been one of the things I hate the most about this language.

http://jazzjuice.blogspot.com/2010/10/6-things-i-hate-about-java-or-scala-is.html

I have listed about 8 suboptimal ways to do variants there.